# get all Values from a Column in a Paged Griview with using linqdatasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, linqdatasource

Iam using a Griview with a linqdatasource which uses a Stored Procedure to get a View.
for Reasons of Performance, it was neccessary to put the "allow paging" Attriute to true.

But for my Gridview i want to have the Sum from a Column (Integer) for all existing Pages.

would be cool if i dont have to call my stored Procedure twice for that (Performance).

it works if i Set the Gridview PAging Attribute t False while making my Calculation, and then switch bak to Paging to true but once again---> Performance PRoblems :/

Do you Guys knows of any Solution for this?

Comment: Please post your code and let us know what went wrong.

Comment: till yet i havent Code, i just want to know if its possible to get a full Column of a datasource when its used by a paging Gridview, and how, like : should i use the LinqDataSource Select Event to build my Sum? and if yes ..how ... maybe someneone had the same Problem and came to a Conclusion?